# Core dump - 32S, 32F, 8U

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to run this sequence of code:

```
DescriptorMatcher * matcher = new BFMatcher(NORM_HAMMING);
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher -> match(descriptorsImage1, descriptorsImage2, matches);
```

It's resulting in this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((type == CV_8U && dtype == CV_32S) || dtype == CV_32F) in batchDistance, file /home/.../OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/stat.cpp, line 2480
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/.../OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/stat.cpp:2480: error: (-215) (type == CV_8U && dtype == CV_32S) || dtype == CV_32F in function batchDistance

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://answers.opencv.org/question/10046/feature-2d-feature-matching-fails-with-assert-statcpp/?answer=10048#post-id-10048.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the comments you may misuse the type of descriptors with their appropriate norm type.

As OpenCV's documentation says:

[`BFMatcher::BFMatcher(int normType=NORM_L2, bool crossCheck=false )`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#bfmatcher-bfmatcher)

`normType` – One of `NORM_L1`, `NORM_L2`, `NORM_HAMMING`, `NORM_HAMMING2`. `L1` and `L2` norms are preferable choices for `SIFT` and `SURF` descriptors, `NORM_HAMMING` should be used with `ORB` and `BRIEF`, `NORM_HAMMING2` should be used with `ORB` when `WTA_K==3` or `4` (see [`ORB::ORB`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#orb-orb) constructor description).